Low False Positive Rates in glmm compared to lmm?
In R, I conducted a reaction time simulation on an interaction effect, where I simulated data with true effects, where the intercept is there, and no effect, where only main effects are present, without an interaction.
As the basis of the simulation I took reaction time means for four conditions that represent a an interaction.
Interaction effect:



Previous condition
Current condition
RT




1
1
800


0
1
820


1
0
860


0
0
840



No interaction effect:



Previous condition
Current condition
RT




1
1
800


0
1
800


1
0
860


0
0
860



In my simulation I implemented random intercept for participants, by a simple normal distribution,
rt_intercept = rnorm(participant_number, 0, 200)

and random slopes for the main and the interaction effects as well in order to be able to fit full random effects structure models. The random slopes were sampled from binomial distributions, so they also correlate.
random_slopes = faux::rnorm_multi(n = as.integer(participant_number),
                                    mu = 0, # means for random effects are 0 
                                    sd = c(20, 5), # set SDs for random slopes 20ms for main; 5ms for interaction 
                                    r = .8, # set correlation 
                                    varnames = c("main_random_slope",
 "interaction_random_slope")  
  )

I created participants by running the above random sampling and adding the effects to them in a manner that it follows the main effect patterns:
mutate(main_random_slope = case_when(current_condition == 1 ~ main_random_slope,
                                     T ~ -main_random_slope), #  noise depending on current congruency
         interaction_random_slope = case_when(
            prev_condition == 1 & current_condition == 1  ~ interaction_random_slope,
           prev_condition == 0 & current_condition == 1  ~ -interaction_random_slope,
           prev_condition == 1 & current_condition == 0  ~ -interaction_random_slope,
           prev_condition == 0 & current_condition == 0 ~ interaction_random_slope, #  noise depending on previous and current congruency condition
           TRUE ~ 0
         )) %>% 
  mutate(mean_rt = RT + rt_intercept + main_random_slope + interaction_random_slope)

I did not simulate any random, or fixed effect for the 'previous condition'. And for the no effect datasets I left in the random slopes for all effects, regardless of the lack of the fixed interaction effect. The above way could generate 4 conditions for every participant.
I then took every participant conditional RT and I plugged it in an EZ diffusion model, which I think is irrelevant here, it was only to populate the participants with trials per condition, where the RT mean is the participants' real mean, but the trial RTs show a positively skewed distribution. I created 80 trials per participant per condition, which generated a large dataset for e.g 200 participants.
I fitted two models to the simulated datasets:

A linear mixed effect model with full random effects structure.

lmer(rt ~ prev_condition * current_condition + (1 + prev_condition * current_condition | participant_id),
 data = data,
 control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa",
 optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)
)



A generalized mixed effect model fitted on an inverse Gaussian, with a log link (as this should be a more appropriate way to test, due to the skewed nature of the data).

glmer(rt ~ prev_condition * current_condition + (1 + prev_condition * current_condition | participant_id),
 data = data,
 family = inverse.gaussian(link = "log"),
 control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa",
 optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)
)

I checked for lower than .05 p-values generated by the lmerTest package, in the interaction predictor, and according to it I decided on true positives and false positive.
Fits to the no-effect data showed, that the false positive rate of the glmm is way smaller than for the lmm. True positive rate was also lower for glmm in the true effect condition.
I am confident that I mess something up in the simulation, because I would expect the false positive rate to be close to alpha, which is the case in LMMs, but not GLMMs, where it was around .005.
Is it maybe due to the unreliable nature of p-values for mixed models? Then why is it working in LMMs, and not GLMMs? Or maybe is it due to the random slopes in the no-effect datasets? But they should affect LMMs too.

Welcome to Cross Validated! It would be helpful to see your code. Could you please post it with comments in the code explaining what it does (or is supposed to do)? $//$ I would not vote to close this as a programming issue. Sure, the problem might be a code bug, but there could be something interesting, statistically, happening, too.

Thanks Dave, I reformatted my question and added some code snippets too.
